# How to run an old angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

In my company there is an old angular (Not even sure what version) client that no one touched for at least 2 years and I got the "lucky" job of changing some feature in this client.

The confusing part starts when I noticed there are no package.json, package-lock.json and angular.json files in the project but the whole node modules directory and compiled js files are stored in the git repository.

The problem is that I have no idea of how to rebuild this project after I change the typescript files. In addition, I want to remove the node modules directory from the git repository and have package.json instead.

No one that originally worked on this project is still in the company (Not surprised after I seen this mess).

The backend is written in asp.net framework and contains .cshtml files so I suspect there is some relation between the client and the server

Can someone help me rescue this project?

Comment: Are there any `gulp` files or tasks?

Comment: Is it at least in a git repository? If so, you may want to look into the repo's history and see if at any point the files you're looking for existed. -- Also are there any bower files?

Comment: Try generating the *package.json* file by doing `npm init`?

Comment: check if it's AngularJs or Angular , if you see Typescript it's Angular, if you see Controllers and ... it's AngularJs

Comment: 1 )It is a git repository, but it is only got migrated to git 6 months ago from tfs. I tried to look for these files but didn't had any luck. 

2) Yes there are typescript files so it must be angular (not js). 

3) what are gulp files? 

4) npm init just creates a package.json but doesn't populate it with the dependecies

Comment: Btw, the backend is writen in asp.net framework and contains .cshtml files so I suspect there is some relation between the client and ther server

Comment: Hot mess! Keep in mind, they may have modified the contents of `node_modules`, so replacing it with a package.json and gitignored node_modules may break things. To be safe, you should do a diff of before and after. Diff the files and their contents too. But I'd just leave it alone, unless you're confident in your testing, to catch anything that breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bit of a nightmare! You can try these steps to start but I'm sure you will have issues. Persevere as I think you can do it! Once you get some errors to work from it will be easier. Good luck

1. Look in node_modules for `@angular/` folder and find the angular
   version (if there isn't one then its AngularJS).
2. Create a brand new project using angular-cli using the version you just found.
3. copy the contents of the app folder (at least) to the new project.
4. Search through imports to see which libraries are used and npm install them.